# Puzzle matching game algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I want to make a puzzle matching game, but I have a problem with the algorithm.

Here's my game - a board, e.g. 4x4 - 16 cells containing 8 pairs of letters. The letters are scrambled.

The requirements are:

- Pairs of letters that aren't blocked by other letters should be joined together
- After a pair of letters join, it will disappear
- You should choose the nearest possible pair of letters to join first

Example image:

[image]

What is the most effective algorithm should I use **to match a pair of alphabet**?

Comment: I don't get it, you want to write a game? Or solver?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question about programming. Please attempt to build a program yourself and when you get stuck ask a very specific question here.

Comment: How about: (1) For each letter, do breadth-first-search of reachable letters, until finding a pair, (2) remove the pair, (3) repeat?

Comment: @andrey : i want to build an assist to a player.. so if the player choose a wrong alphabet, the program alert the player..

Comment: @tobias: are breadth-first search faster than a-star? or i dont need to use a-star?

Comment: @user2981567 what do you mean assist? Be *very* specific or your question will be closed.

Comment: @tobias_k, that's not very efficient, seems to me like you could use a single search per cycle and find closest matching letters from it. Perhaps you can even do a smarter search that can see through obstructions and would help the next step

Comment: @Leenor Maybe, but it's definitely a start. When that's working, OP can try to get it more efficient, if its to slow (for much, much larger grids maybe).  The other question: I see no sense in using A* here, since you have to target and uniform-cost steps.

Comment: Speaking about efficiency when having 4x4 field doesn't make a lot of sense. Unless you are running it massively on server you really don't care.

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to write code, nor go into too much detail, so here is just a rough sketch of an algorithm. Iterate through all letters:

1. Take one letter
2. Find all its neighbors.
3. If a neighbor is the same letter then you have found a match.
4. If a neighbor is empty space then recursively find its neighbors in search for a match.
5. If you've found a match remember the path (especially the path length)

When iterating you are interested in shortest path, so you must always iterate until the end, or if you have found the shortest path possible (adjacent pair).

Comment: @user2981567 Recursion usually implies depth-first search, so maybe it's the wrong word here. Breadth-first search is better suited here, because you want the shortest path. However, this table is very small, and with recursion the code would be simpler, with not much cost to efficiency.

Comment: @user2981567 I could be wrong, though. In picture 8, when matching two Ds, recursion depth is 15 in worst case, with 3-4 options in each step (approximately 3.5), which gives 3.5^15=144 million searches. Better use breadth-first :)

Comment: @user2981567 hmm, bad math can get us anywhere. Worst case recursion depth is 15, but there are 2-3 options in each step (because one option is the one where we came from), and only at the beginning, and it becomes 1-2 options after 7-8 steps, so it's more like 2.5^8*1.5^7=26000 searches, which is not all that much.